# sharepont 2013 workflow to loop list items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-list, archive

I am trying to create a workflow which loops through the list items and archive them to another list based on modified date. 
i am using sharepoint 2013 
can anyone help on same?

Comment: Writing a comment as this doesn't answer your question exactly, but...


SharePoint 2010 Workflows do not support looping, however SharePoint 2013 Workflows DO support looping. You need to have the SharePoint 2013 Workflow system installed before you can use SharePoint 2013 Workflows.

However, you could use a SharePoint 2010 workflow that is triggered by an Information Management Policy set on the library.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements you can use **Call HTTP Web Service** action to loop through the list items and **Create List Item**.

Below article covers how to loop through list items:

[WORKFLOW LOOP THROUGH MULTIPLE SHAREPOINT ITEMS](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/).

You can get the field values and store them in workflow variable and then use **Create List Item** action to create list item.

Below article covers how to create list item using SharePoint designer workflow 2013:

[SharePoint Designer 2013: Create List Item Action](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-designer-2013-create-list-item-action).